# Html table tag not properly display when text inside is longer than other

Tags: html, css

I have been try to make an html and css lines to display user image, name, old file name, new file name and date.
My problem is when the whole content has the same length it will look good but if the username is longer or another other sting is longer it will deform the table and design please i need help.

Below is a sample image and jsfiddle link

[image]

Here is bad side

[image]

Here is my html code

```
<table>
<tr class="treeFile">
<td>
<img src="Pictures/b78d7cd4555821042a70d9ec034b0dea.PNG" alt="Front" class="treeimage"/>
<span class="treposition" align="center">                   
<span class="treeSenderline"><span class="treeName"><a href="">Ujah peter</a></span></span>
<span class="treeSenderXXX"></span>
</span>
</td>
<td width="1px"></td>
<td align="center">
<div class="treeMain">
<span class="fromtree"><a href=""><strong>Mainprojectarea</strong></a></span>
<span><a href=""><strong>Newprojectarea</strong></a></span>
<span class="treeBottomLine">10-28-2016</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="treeFile">
<td>
<img src="Pictures/b78d7cd4555821042a70d9ec034b0dea.PNG" alt="Front" class="treeimage"/>
<span class="treposition" align="center">                   
<span class="treeSenderline"><span class="treeName"><a href="">micheal grayer</a></span></span>
<span class="treeSenderXXX"></span>
</span>
</td>
<td width="1px"></td>
<td align="center">
<div class="treeMain">
<span class="fromtree"><a href=""><strong>Mainprojectareaxxx</strong></a></span>
<span><a href=""><strong>Newprojectlocation</strong></a></span>
<span class="treeBottomLine">10-28-2016</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is css code

```
.treeBottomLine{
border-bottom: 2px solid #337ab7;
display: block;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 60%;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
align-content: center;
border-left: 2px solid #337ab7;
border-right: 2px solid #337ab7;
background-color: #fff;
}
.fromtree{
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 2px solid #337ab7;
border-left: 2px solid #337ab7;
border-right: 2px solid #337ab7;
padding: 3px;
margin-right: 3em;
background-color: #fff;
}
.treeimage{
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #337ab7;
background-color: #fff;
margin: 5px;
margin-right: 1em;
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
.treeName{
border: 2px solid #337ab7;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 3px;
margin-left: 2em;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;

}
.treeSender{
border-top: 2px solid #337ab7;
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
top: -2.6em;
left: 33px;
z-index: 0;
}
.treeSenderline{    
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 2.6em;
top: -2em;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
background-color: #337ab7;
width: 100%;
height: 3px;
}
.treeMain{
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is a link to https://jsfiddle.net/evr50w05/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is to float the blue line to the left, and add a margin:

```
.treeMain {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 33px;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/9m7mchyL/1/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: please see the first sample image i attached that what am trying to make

Comment: Oh sorry you got it i just expand the result view and it look better